# Button to the right side but without moving with the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

Hellos,

I've got a site with a table on it and a button on the bottom. But when the table gets too long on some sites I need to scroll. The problem: It's in a digital signage player which doesnt support scrollbars. So I need to add a button to move down a bit. 
Thats completly done.

My problem is. The button should remain on the right side and 50% from the top - but the 50% needs to be the visible area, not the complete one with the long list. Also when the page gets scrolled down it should remain always in the middle on the right side.

At the moment it is that way: when I display it in the middle it's in the middle from the complete side, but not from the visible.

As example... When you ask a question here you see this "similar questions" box on the right side? it's also that way.. it's scrolling with you

```
button css:
.buttonscrolldown {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
float: right;
#   display: block;
#   padding-top: 100px;
padding-top: 50%;
display: absolute;
margin-right: 20px;
}


<script>
function scrollWindown() {
window.scrollBy(0, 100);
}
function scrollWinup() {
window.scrollBy(0, -100);
}
</script>

<a onclick="scrollWinup()"><img src='images/backwf.png' 
class='buttonscrollup'></a><br><br>
<?php
echo "<div class='content'><table class='departmenttext'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("database/all.csv", "r");
$lineCount = 0;
fgetcsv($f);
 while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
if ( count($line)<2 )   {
    break;
}
if ($lineCount % 2 == 0) {
    echo "<tr class='departmenttext'>";
}
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($line[0]) . "</td>";
echo "<td class='faketablesmall'></td>";
echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars(substr($line[1],-3)) . "</td>";
echo "<td class='faketablemiddle'></td>";

if ($lineCount % 2 == 1) {
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
$lineCount = $lineCount + 1;
}
if ($lineCount % 2 == 1) {
echo "</tr>\n";
 }
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></div>";
?>


<a href='departments.php'><img src='images/backwf.png' class='button'></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add your code for better understanding

Comment: done with the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```css
div#your-player {
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
}

button#the-button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="your-player" />
  <button id="the-button">press me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In my case I had to do two button css entrys (one for up and one for down) but it's working perfectly. thank you very much. Solution was added.